# Dictionary in VBScript How key is recognized by dictionary object in VBSCript

Tags: vbscript

How key is recognized by dictionary object in VBSCript, I mean to say it consider "ABC" and "BCA" as a same Key...??
means I am trying this it is giving me an error that this key already exists so anyone can please give some details about it.

Comment: Not very interesting as long as we cannot see what you´ve tried. Please post a simple example of what does not work.

Comment: From the docs. A Dictionary object is the equivalent of a PERL associative array. Items can be any form of data, and are stored in the array. Each item is associated with a unique key. The key is used to retrieve an individual item and is usually an integer or a string, but can be anything except an array.
BCA and ABC won't be the same key. If in doubt print out your keys. Returns an array containing all existing keys in a Dictionary object.

 

object.Keys( ) 
 
So a for loop msgboxing you keys.

Comment: Do you have a watch on that dictionary key? That instantly creates the key and when you try to .Add it, it gets seen as existing. "ABC" and "BCA" are certainly NOT seen as the same. (_in this part I stated that the integer `42` and the string `"42"` are seen as identical which is not true. See the post of @Ekkehard.Horner below_) Keys are unique on their scalar values (so 42 is different then "42") or their object reference (Yes! You can use objects as Keys!).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I need formatting to point out a pecularity of VBScript's dictionary/dispute AutomatedChaos' claim. A Scripting.Dictionary accepts keys of all simple/scalar data types and even objects. So having two keys 42 and "42" is no problem:

```
>> set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> dic.Add "42", 1
>> dic.Add 42, 2
>>
>> WScript.Echo Join(dic.Keys)
>>
42 42
```

Comment: You are so right, how could that mis-knowledge slip into my mind?

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary.key is the indicator for a stored item under the Dictionary object.

[Microsoft Dictionary.Key Example:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ex01tte%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

```
'Dictionary.Item("{key}") returns the item information.
'Dictionary.Key("{oldkey}") = "{newkey}" stores a new key for a Dictionary entry. 
Function DictDemo
   Dim d   ' Create some variables.
   Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   d.Add "a", "Athens"   ' Add some keys and items, "a" = key, "Athens" = item
   d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
   d.Add "c", "Cairo"
   d.Key("c") = "d"   ' Set key for "c" to "d".
   DictDemo = d.Item("d")   ' Return associate item.
End Function
```

[How to discover which keys you have populated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/etzd1tzc%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

```
Function DictDemo
   Dim a, d, i   ' Create some variables.
   Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   d.Add "a", "Athens"   ' Add some keys and items.
   d.Add "b", "Belgrade"
   d.Add "c", "Cairo"

   a = d.Keys   ' Get the keys.

   For i = 0 To d.Count -1 ' Iterate the array.
      s = s & a(i) & "<BR>" ' Return results.
   Next
   DictDemo = s
End Function
```